# C - segmentation core dump on strcpy()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, strcpy

I get a segmentation fault each time I'm trying to run this function.

```
char *hist_array[20];
int history_counter = 0;

void save_to_history(char *temp){
    temp = malloc(512);/*512 is the size of temp array*/
    printf("temp = %s\narray = %s",temp,hist_array[history_counter]);/*debug*/
    strcpy(hist_array[history_counter],temp);
    printf("Saved %s to history to %d\n\n",hist_array[history_counter],history_counter);
    history_counter++;
}
```

I'm not sure whether I'm using `malloc` correctly or not, but as I understand it should help with properly saving my string `temp` to an array of strings `hist_array`. Also, temp is never `NULL`.

**EDIT 1:** Changed sizeof(temp) to its proper size 512, still getting `segfault`.

Comment: Nope, this won't work. sizeof(temp) is the size of the pointer, not the passed in string.  You need to pass in the string size as a parameter.

Comment: You also appear to be overwriting the pointer which was passed in with a pointer to a new uninitialized block of memory - then using it as a source for a strcpy.

Comment: @OldProgrammer @Baldrick I've changed the `sizeof(temp)` to it's proper value, still getting segfault. 

@Baldrick so I need to initialize the array `hist_array`?

Comment: did you allocated memory for pointers in `hist_array` somewhere? If not - that is the reason for segfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the following statement -

```
strcpy(hist_array[history_counter], temp);
```

`strcpy` tries to copy the buffer pointed to by `temp` to the buffer pointed to by `hist_array[history_counter]` but `char *hist_array[20];` defines `hist_array` to be an array of 20 pointers to characters. You should change your function to -

```
char *hist_array[20];
int history_counter = 0;

void save_to_history(char *temp) {
    // +1 for the terminating null byte as strlen
    // does not count the null byte

    hist_array[history_counter] = malloc(1 + strlen(temp)); 
    if(hist_array[history_counter] == NULL) {
        printf("not enough memory to allocate\n");
        // handle it
    }
    strcpy(hist_array[history_counter], temp);
    printf("Saved %s to history to %d\n\n",
           hist_array[history_counter], 
           history_counter);

    history_counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are allocating via `malloc` but you don't initialize it. So when you do this:

```
printf("temp = %s\narray = %s",temp,hist_array[history_counter]);/*debug*/
strcpy(hist_array[history_counter],temp);
```

The should print some garbage and the subsequent strcpy will copy whatever is in temp at the time, until it encounters a 0 byte. You are invoking undefined behaviour here, because you should initialize the memory.

For example you could do:

```
memset(temp, 0, 512);
```

Additionally you are dereferencing pointers in your array `hist_array`. Since this is a global variable, all the pointers will originally be NULL pointers, which is causing your segfaul there.